# Existence of a group with a condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove or disprove: For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ exists a group $G_n$ such that for all $1<m\leq n$ exists an organ $a\in G_n \setminus\{e\} $ such that $a^m=e$.

I would like for some essitence. I thought about it that if the sentence is true, then I should find $G_n$ such that $|G_n|\gg n$.

Comment: Take a direct product of cyclic groups - or $G=S_n$.

Comment: Or take the additive group $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, if you have a groups $G_1,...,G_n$ with elements $a_1,...,a_n$ or order $m_1,...,m_n$, then the direct product $G_1 \times ... \times G_n$ has elements of order $m_i$ for all $i$, simply by considering the elements $(e_{G_1},e_{G_2},e_{G_3},...,a_i,...,e_{G_n})$ where $a_i$ occurs at the $i$th place, for $1 \leq i \leq m$.

---

With this in mind, clearly we know that $\mathbb Z_m = \frac {\mathbb Z}{m \mathbb Z}$ is a cyclic group of order $m$, with $\bar 1$ having order $m$. Thus, the direct product $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^m \mathbb Z_{i}$ contains elements of orders $1,...,m$ (a stronger statement than the one given, since this specifies the order of the element rather than just being identity when taken to that power).

---

Certainly, the order of this group is $n!$, much larger than $n$. It would be interesting to see which is the smallest(cardinality) group with this property for a given $n$. Also, note that the infinite product $\prod \mathbb Z_m$ contains elements of all orders.

---